# Blender's "View Animation Ctrl F11" shows purple (missing image) background instead of transparency in 2.83 / 2.90

Tags: rendering, animation, transparency

The title almost says it all. In previous Blender versions, when I rendered images with transparent background and saved them as PNG sequence, I could play the animation in Blender with "View Animation" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) and the animation had a transparent background.

Now in Blender 2.83 LTS (and I checked a 2.90 test build as well), the background is no longer shown as transparent, but purple like there is a missing texture or image. And it doesn't matter if I used an HDRI as background or just the default grey color. The player always shows the animation with a purple background. I tried switching from PNG to TIF and EXR, all the files are rendered and saved correctly with transparency - but the internal blender player seems to be unable to show transparency. Using an older 2.79 version playing the same image sequence shows correct transparency. Is there a setting I can't find to change it back to how it was before?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you saying that when you actually press Ctrl + F11, the animation actually plays? Because I have personally found that while this shortcut does indeed appear in the Render menu, pressing the shortcut on the keyboard does nothing. Moreover, I've found that this has been the case for me ever since I've been using some flavor of 2.8. I have to manually use the Render menu to get the animation to playback. So while you're problem definitely sound annoying, in a way, I see you as luckier than I.

Comment: I guess you're right, I might be luckier than you, but anyway it doesn't help me ;-)  Have you tried to restore the shortcut? But you should open an extra thread for that because it's a different problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a bug. In the latest build this doesn't happen anymore.